# Rails Form Passing Incorrect ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 app, I'm trying to create a form that updates my User model using a new action I created.

However, I'm running into a 404 error (but the record's there since the current values show in the form).  I think it's because the User.id isn't passing correctly in the form, but I'm unsure.

Error:
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`

```
Started PATCH "/users/submit_info" for ::1 at 2017-01-24 23:02:31 -0800
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"Foo"}, "commit"=>"Submit Details", "id"=>"submit_info"}
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`slug` = 'submit_info' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

view

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: submit_info_users_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

controller

```
def submit_info
  @user = User.friendly.find(current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :info }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# I'm using the Friendly_ID gem
def set_user
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"  }
resources :users do 
  collection do
    get 'info'
    post 'submit_info'
  end
end
```

Comment: In your url you didn't pass the user probably: `submit_info_users_path(@user)` so the id being sent is `submit_info`

Comment: I get the same result when I try that, or if I try `submit_info_users_path(:id=>@user.id)`

Comment: Aah sorry I didn't notice you have mentioned the `submit_info` in `collection` route it should be in a `member` route because you want to update the user using that action.

Comment: I think that works! I had to add this `match 'submit_info', to: 'users#submit_info', via: [:patch]`.  However, I'm getting this error `undefined local variable or method `user_params' for #<UsersController:0xa7bda60>` because of this line in the controller `if @user.save(user_params)`.  Do you know why this is causing an issue?  Thanks!

Comment: In your `users_controller` did you define the strong params method? `def user_params` and instead of `match` use `member` routes.

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to update a particular user and you have mentioned the action in `collection` routes. Instead it should be in `member` routes:

```
resources :users do 
  collection do
    get 'info'
  end
  member do
    post 'submit_info'
  end
end
```

So this `member` route will ensure the correct `id` of user in the routes when you pass in the path. The `collection` routes is used for collection of objects like the user index page where you list all the users.

And as you were facing issues on `user_params` so for strong parameters you need to define the method in your controller:

```
def user_params
  # permitted attributes
end
```

This should be defined as a `private` method in your controller (not compulsory but a good practice).